# Sweep collision between two moving spheres?

Tags: c#, collision, code-translation

I'm trying to figure out a function to detect collision between two moving spheres as explained in [THIS ARTICLE](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131790/simple_intersection_tests_for_games.php?page=2), but I have no clue in what language the example in the article is in so I don't know how I should translate it to C# (the language I'm programming in)

Could someone either:

- Tell me what language the example code is in?
- Translate the example code into C#
- Or explain to me, who's new to this kind of programming, how Sphere-Sphere Sweep Collision works so I can try to implement it myself

I'm grateful for any answer, since I've been stuck with this for a while now.

---

Here's the example code in the so far unidentified language:

```
#include "vector.h"

template< class T >

inline void SWAP( T& a, T& b )
//swap the values of a and b

{



const T temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
}

// Return true if r1 and r2 are real
inline bool QuadraticFormula
(
const SCALAR a,
const SCALAR b,
const SCALAR c,
SCALAR& r1,  //first
SCALAR& r2   //and second roots
)

{




const SCALAR q = b*b - 4*a*c; 
if( q >= 0 )

{




const SCALAR sq = sqrt(q);
const SCALAR d = 1 / (2*a);
r1 = ( -b + sq ) * d;
r2 = ( -b - sq ) * d;
return true;//real roots

}

else

{




return false;//complex roots

}

}

const bool SphereSphereSweep
(
const SCALAR    ra, //radius of sphere A
const VECTOR&   A0, //previous position of sphere A
const VECTOR&   A1, //current position of sphere A
const SCALAR    rb, //radius of sphere B
const VECTOR&   B0, //previous position of sphere B
const VECTOR&   B1, //current position of sphere B
SCALAR&  u0,    //normalized time of first collision
SCALAR&  u1 //normalized time of second collision

)

{



const VECTOR va = A1 - A0;
//vector from A0 to A1

const VECTOR vb = B1 - B0;
//vector from B0 to B1

const VECTOR AB = B0 - A0;
//vector from A0 to B0

const VECTOR vab = vb - va;
//relative velocity (in normalized time)

const SCALAR rab = ra + rb;

const SCALAR a = vab.dot(vab);
//u*u coefficient

const SCALAR b = 2*vab.dot(AB);
//u coefficient

const SCALAR c = AB.dot(AB) - rab*rab;
//constant term
//check if they're currently overlapping
if( AB.dot(AB) <= rab*rab )

{




u0 = 0;
u1 = 0;
return true;

}

//check if they hit each other 
// during the frame
if( QuadraticFormula( a, b, c, u0, u1 ) )
{




if( u0 > u1 )
SWAP( u0, u1 );
return true;

}

return false;

}
```

Comment: It's C++ with a (likely) DX/OpenGL framework...although I guess they could be using any math-related library too.

Comment: What does SCALAR and SCALAR& stand for?

Comment: The unidentified language is C++ and this is relatively straightforward to translate to C#. You can find out more about the collision of spheres with use of the quadratic function `d = b^2 - 4ac` at http://twobitcoder.blogspot.be/2010/04/circle-collision-detection.html.

Comment: Google is your friend :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)

The SCALAR& declaration is pointing to the variable's memory address...also known as a reference operator http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: This is duplicate of well-answered gamedev question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/313/what-is-a-good-algorithm-to-detect-collision-between-moving-spheres